# What is the URI for SMS Draft Content Provider?

Tags: sms, android-contentprovider

What is the Native Content URI for SMS Drafts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content Provider URI for SMS is commonly

```
   content://sms/...
```

and for SMS Drafts it is

```
   content://sms/drafts/
```

Answer (score 11):

You can open each SMS message part by opening different ways.

1. Inbox = `"content://sms/inbox"`
2. Failed = `"content://sms/failed"`
3. Queued = `"content://sms/queued"`
4. Sent = `"content://sms/sent"`
5. Draft = `"content://sms/draft"`
6. Outbox = `"content://sms/outbox"`
7. Undelivered = `"content://sms/undelivered"`
8. All = `"content://sms/all"`
9. Conversations = `"content://sms/conversations"`.